# CSV not reading

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with my code which is included as an image. The problem is with the part that writes to the CSV file. It either comes up as not letting me write to the file or says the CSV is unreadable.

[image]

```
import csv

def checkstock():
    print('''The products that can be stocked are:
Apples    : 46527851
Chickens  : 39647511
Oranges   : 46912848
Toys      : 63891379
Pens      : 46873262
Water     : 38509162''')

    barcode=input('Please enter the GTIN of the product you want to check the stock for: ')
    with open('Stock.csv', 'r') as data:
        file=csv.reader(data)
        for row in file:
            if barcode in row:
                product1=row
                print(product1)

    name=product1[0]
    box=int(product1[1])
    currentstock=int(product1[2])
    minstock=int(product1[3])
    orderbox=int(product1[4])
    barcode=int(product1[5])

    needstock=int(currentstock-minstock)
    list3=[]
    if needstock <= 0:
        print('Order needed for pens, please order ' + orderbox + 'boxes of' + name)
        with open('Stock.csv', 'w') as data:
            file=csv.reader(data)
            list3.extend(file)
            overwrite={line[product1,'Yes']}
            with open('Stock.csv', 'w') as data:
                writer = csv.writer(data)
                for line, row in enumerate(list3):
                    data1 = overwrite.get(line, row)
                    writer.writerow(data1)

    else:
        print('The current level of ' + name + ' is sufficient.')
        with open('Stock.csv', 'w') as data:
            file=csv.reader(data)
            list3.extend(file)
            overwrite={line[product1,'No']}
            with open('Stock.csv', 'wb') as data:
                writer = csv.writer(data)
                for line, row in enumerate(list3):
                    data1 = overwrite.get(line, row)
                    writer.writerow(data1)

    repeat=input('Would you like to check the stock of another item? (Y or N) ')
    if repeat == 'Y':
        checkstock()
    if repeat == 'N':
        start()



    choice=input('''Would you like to either:      (Please enter a capial letter)
    (A) Check stock,
    (B) Record a delivery of products or,
    (C) See what needs to be delivered or,
    (D) Update a stock level: ''')

    if choice == 'A':
         checkstock()
    if choice == 'B':
        recStock()
    if choice == 'C':
        inOrder()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the code but I can see some problems:

```
with open('Stock.csv', 'w') as data:
        file=csv.reader(data)
        list3.extend(file)
        overwrite={line[product1,'Yes']}
```

You can't make a csv.reader with a 'w' access to a file.
You can only have a csv.writer()
Also, I would recommend not to write in the file you are reading with csv.

What are you trying to do with the read/write part?